# Discrete maths and circles

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Finitely many Real numbers are written along a circle. If some four successive numbers $a ,b ,c$ and $d$ satisfy the inequality $(a-d)(b-c)>0$,then it is permitted to transpose(exchange positions of $b$ and $c$) the numbers b and c. Prove that it is impossible to perform infinitely many such operations. I tried to see that to have infinite operations we must return to the original permutations of numbers, then tried to prove by contradiction,but couldn't. Also,I observed that $a>b>c....$ works for most part except for last part giving contradiction $a>b>c....>a$

Comment: You should clarify that finitely many number are written. If we're allowed infinitely many, we can group then into 4's that allow the swapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a-d)(b-c)>0$

implies $ab+cd>ac+bd$

implies $ab+cd+bc+ad>ac+bd+bc+ad$

implies $(a+c)(b+d)>(a+b)(c+d)$

implies $(a+c)(c+b)(b+d)>(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)$

This means when we perform a transpose action, the consecutive product of pairwise sums strictly increases.

Let the numbers be $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n$. We can deduce that the product $(x_1+x_2)(x_2+x_3)(x_3+x_4)...(x_{n-1}+x_n)(x_n+x_1)$ always increases after a transpose action. Since there are only a finite number of possible products the result is proven.

Edit: the above proves the case where all numbers are positive. However since the result does not change if we add a constant to all numbers so we can add "the smallest number $+ 1$" to all numbers to make them all positive without affecting the result.